# Error: Can't find stylesheet to import. ╷ 2 │ @use '@angular/material' as mat;

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, 500);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-primary,
    accent: $my-accent,
  ),
  density: 0,
));


@include mat.core-theme($my-theme);


@include mat.button-theme($my-theme);

Here's the code I wrote in the root style.scss of the Angular proposal and got an error

cmd.exe /D /C call C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.cmd styles.scss:styles.css
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @use '@angular/material' as mat;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  styles.scss 2:1  root stylesheet

Process finished with exit code 65
```